# Handler call error in tell block in Applescript

Tags: applescript

Why a handler is not called within the tell block?
Error is -1708

```
on stub() -- method is not called in tell block
end stub

tell application "Finder"
    stub()
end tell
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Within a `tell SOMETHING` block, AppleScript looks up commands within `SOMETHING`.  In this case, it's looking for a `stub` command within `application "Finder"`; this obviously doesn't exist.  To tell AppleScript to look up the function you've defined, you write `my stub()`; the `my` forces it to look in the body of the current script rather than in `application "Finder"`.  In this case, this gives you:

```
on stub()
    -- ...
end stub

-- ...
stub() -- Works fine
-- ...

tell application "Finder"
    -- ...
    my stub() -- With the `my`, works fine
    -- ...
end tell
```